# Node MongoDB collection.findOne() returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my code:

```js
let token
console.log({'sessionId': session})
collection.findOne({'sessionId': session}, async (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err
    else if(res) token = res
})
```

And the document looks like this:

```json
{"sessionId":"E85@\'}rqY4/[E+A`[1h`A0i/","user":"123456789"}
```

When I put the query from the `console.log()` into MongoDB Compass and find it works properly. However, when I run the code it returns null for both `err` and `res`. Are there some additional arguments I have to pass? I have done `client.connect()` and `insertOne()` seems to work.

Comment: Can you post here what you see in the console from `console.log()`?

Comment: Please log the `session` variable and check it.  My guess is that you are trying to find a session which is not in your collection.

Comment: The `console.log` also logs the session which is correct and is found when I search it in MongoDB Compass, as mentioned above. It looks like this: `{sessionId: '5|$3XwGb=&tV-=$wwl=s?E_+q'}`, and when I put this in Compass I can find the document.

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: No, the official Mongo driver.

Comment: Try escaping special characters. Something like this: `findOne({'sessionId': session.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')}, async (err, res) => {`

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work, but the escaped query works in Compass. I also suspect it is because of the special characters after reading your comment, but changing the random strings to numbers also does not seem to work, with the same result.

Comment: I tried another string generator which returns numbers and letters only, also did not work.

Comment: I found the issue and it was related to my code, not the MongoDB driver. Still thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: it was because of the flow in my code. I am making a Discord oauth2 application. The steps of the user authorising and logging in is supposed to be as follows:

1. User authorises from Discord and gets redirected to /oauthed.
2. /oauthed then fetches access token and everything else, generates a `session` and stores everything in the database. The client also stores `session` in the cookie through `Set-Cookie` header.
3. /oauthed redirects to /app which is the destination page.
4. /app searches for access token in the database by the `session` cookie from the client.

What happened was that due to api requests having delays, step 2 actually stores it after step 4, causing this weird issue. The moral of the story here is to use `async` and `await` whenever possible.